# How improve query performance while dealing characters like "_", "-", "." during facet generation in Marklogic8

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-8

I have 200k documents in my MarkLogic 8 database. Each document has a title element with string values joined by characters like "_", "-", "." but values are not unique.

I created a facet on title by setting up a range index in the Admin API. After that my search query takes lots of time to process. I even tried to create a field and field range index on title by using tokenizer-class to remove three characters. But still facing same issue on performance. Is there any way to improve query performance?

some sample title values in my xml documents

```
<title>04_COL_9921_Ch03_213_344.indd</title>
<title>Sch4e_fig_9_10.ai</title>
<title>10027 Separation of plasmid DNA.ai</title>
<title>MCK_03598_12_P06.psd</title>

let $options :=
  <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
    <search-option>unfiltered</search-option>
    <term>
      <term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
    </term>
    <constraint name="Title">
      <range collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/" facet="true">
        <field ns="" name="title" />
      </range>
    </constraint>
    <return-results>true</return-results>
    <return-query>true</return-query>
  </options>
let $result := search:search("**", $options, 1, 20)
return $result
```

Field

```
<field>
  <field-name>title</field-name>
  <field-path>
    <path>content/feed/descriptive/title</path>
    <weight>1.0</weight>
  </field-path>
  <word-lexicons/>
  <included-elements/>
  <excluded-elements/>
  <tokenizer-overrides>
    <tokenizer-override>
      <character>_</character>
      <tokenizer-class>remove</tokenizer-class>
    </tokenizer-override>
    <tokenizer-override>
      <character>-</character>
      <tokenizer-class>remove</tokenizer-class>
    </tokenizer-override>
    <tokenizer-override>
      <character>.</character>
      <tokenizer-class>remove</tokenizer-class>
    </tokenizer-override>
  </tokenizer-overrides>
  <stemmed-searches>basic</stemmed-searches>
  <fast-phrase-searches>true</fast-phrase-searches>
  <fast-case-sensitive-searches>true</fast-case-sensitive-searches>
  <fast-diacritic-sensitive-searches>true</fast-diacritic-sensitive-searches>
  <three-character-searches>true</three-character-searches>
</field>
```

Field Range index

```
<range-field-index>
  <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
  <field-name>title</field-name>
  <collation>http://marklogic.com/collation/</collation>
  <range-value-positions>false</range-value-positions>
</range-field-index>
```

Comment: perhaps share the types if queries you are trying to run.

Comment: @David both index set up <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>

Comment: Can you provide full detail on the indexes created, what queries, and how you are running them?

Comment: @Geert just check above I added my code part

Comment: What are the two ** meant to be in your query?  can you give a few samples of the input strinigs you would expect to use? Also, you are actually not using the title constraint at all in the sample from what I can see. so, a few input string examples for the search and a few of the expected title matches would help.

Comment: Also, how long are your queries taking and how long would you like them to take?